# How to set default time with date formatter using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to changing the `date` format from `"MMM dd, yyyy"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"` by using below `formattedDateFromString` function. Here, Time I am not sending during the format change but by default in result after format change I am getting `12:00:00`. I need to set it is `11:00:00`.

```
let result = formattedDateFromString(dateString: "Sep 20, 2019"), withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss")

func formattedDateFromString(dateString: String, withFormat format: String) -> String? {
    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
    if let date = inputFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        print(date)
        let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        outputFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return outputFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        print("nope")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You want 11:00:00? Because currently, "Sep 20, 2019" has no hour/min/sec. What about using `"yyyy-MM-dd '11:00:00'"` if needed?

Comment: Confusing.  Converting from a date to a date-time?  Why not convert from string to date object, set the time to `11:00:00` and then format that to a string?

Comment: @trojanfoe I will try and update you here.

Comment: @Larme `Sep 20, 2019` I am passing. I used above function to convert like `"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"`. I am getting `12:00:00` but I need to get `11:00:00`

Comment: I meant: `let result = formattedDateFromString(dateString: "Sep 20, 2019", withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd '11:00:00'")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to add 11 Hours *hard-coded*.

And one date formatter is sufficient

```
func formattedDateFromString(dateString: String, withFormat format: String) -> String? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH"
    guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateString + " 11") else { print("nope"); return nil }
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```